# How do I Share Class Variables Between Inherited Instance?

Tags: python

I have two Classes, and I want them to able to share a common list without having to pass it as a parameter. I also want to create a method that will scramble that list, and I want the list to be the same newly scrambled list in both Class A and Class B.

I figured this was a case for inheritance, so I made a Parent Class and set the list as a class attribute and made a method to scramble, but the list variable is oddly enough being now treated as an instance variable of the children.

```py
class A:
    lst = []
    target = 0

    def generateNewLst(self, randomRange, listSize):
        self.lst = [random.randint(*randomRange) for i in range(listSize)]

class B(A):
    pass

class C(A):
    pass
```

My inherited method works just fine:

```
a = B()
a.generateNewLst((0, 10), 3)
a.lst  # => [2,5,7]
```

but when I create another A:

```
b = B()
b.lst  # => [] not shared
```

I know this can be solved by just making my `lst` variable an A specific class attribute, but that won't solve the more important below issue...

```
c = C()
c.lst  # => [] not shared
```

How should I reorganize my setup to work the way I want it to?

Answer (score 0):

`self` is an instance, so setting `self.lst` only sets on that instance. You want to set this variable on the class `A`:

```
A.lst = [...]
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `self.lst = [random.randint(*randomRange) for i in range(listSize)]`, try instead: `A.lst = [random.randint(*randomRange) for i in range(listSize)]`.

When doing `self.lst = ...`, you are creating an instance variable called `lst`, which is now instance specific and thus not shared.

Similarly, instead of doing `b.lst = []`, you should do `A.lst = []` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Mutate that list instead of assigning to a totally new value.

Every time you want to use

```py
b.lst = ...something...
```

Use this instead

```py
b.lst[:] = ...something...
```

---

Another way is to use `property` but it destroys `A.lst`:

```py
class A:
    target = 0
    _lst = []
    @property
    def lst(self):
        return A._lst
    @lst.setter
    def lst(self, value):
        A._lst[:] = value
    def generateNewLst(self, randomRange, listSize):
        self.lst = [random.randint(*randomRange) for i in range(listSize)]

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super()

a=A()
a.lst = [1]
b=B()
b.lst  # [1]
A.lst  # <property object at 0x{some random-ish hex number}>
```